# Timus Online Judge Sudoku problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, puzzle

I was looking at the problem [Magic Square](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=51&num=8)
I am sure with some loop and if condition this problem can be solve, but I am interested to know if there is any know algorithm / datastructure to solve this problem. I am not interested in exact solution, but any hint toward algorithm/datastructure would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a description of sudoku, generalized to squares of different size.  There are several known sudoku solvers; you would have to adapt them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice algorithm from Donald Knuth: [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X), [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links)

As I know it is one of the fastest algorithms to solve Sudoku.

And here is quite readable and through paper with nice pictures: http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0011047